# Espresso Read String File Value

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to keep a Sting and Raw file in my androidTest module and read it when needed in Espresso test.

I keep res folder under androidTest and able to sync and generate R file for the same. But when I tried to access string resource using

`getTargetContext.getString(R.string.product_name)` or using `mAcitivityRule.getActivity.getString(R.string.product_name)`I am getting some random value which is even not used anywhere in resource file.

```
String output: "res/drawable-v21/abc_action_bar_item_background_material.xml"
```

Is there any way I can keep and use String resource in my project test module and it will not add into my production build.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()` instead of `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` and then use appropriate package for generated R file (by default it will append `.test` to your package):

```
Resources resources = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getResources();
String name = resources.getString(com.your_package.test.R.string.product_name);
```

Pay attention to `test` part in resource name.

Comment: Should this go in the `@Before` setUp method?

Answer (score 1):

In 2019 we should do (Kotlin).

```
val resources = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<App>().resources

val description = resources.getString(DESCRIPTION)
```

Comment: This is for a file in the `androidTest` module, not in the `main` module. Using `getApplicationContext` returns a context that only has visibility into the `main` module, so this will throw a `ResourceNotFoundException`

Comment: @HeathBorders, this is not the case if you import `androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider`